# chrome doesnt load external script after using nginx and lets encrypt

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nginx

I am currently using nginx reverse proxy for my website, which has subdomains and used let's encrypt as the ssl authority. My website works fine in firefox and safari. However in chrome, My website doesnt seem to load the external scripts as it constantly fails.I even tried to see if the requests are reaching my proxy server,which it doesnt. Hence, it doesnt  load any of my external script. It gives a net:ERR_FAILED. I have added the screenshots of the console log. However, self signed certificates load the website.

Here is how I call the external script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the code of my nginx server:

```
upstream platform {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    #server 192.0.0.1 backup;
}

server {


        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name test.example.com; # managed by Certbot
        add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 3600;
        add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then

                if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                        return 204;
                }
                proxy_set_header Host test.example.com;
                sub_filter "127.0.0.1:8081" "test.example.com";
                proxy_pass http://test;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        }
        location /.well-known/ {
                root /var/www/html/;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/private.key;
}




server {
        if ($host = test.example.com) {
              return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
        server_name test.example.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

[image: request header example]

[image: console log error]

Comment: your nginx server settings would have absolutely no impact on a browser fetching a resource from some server that isn't yours - it's some failure in chrome, try upgrading or downgrading chrome to see if that changes anything

Comment: I have tried 4 versions of chrome and in different os. They all seem to fail. This only happens when adding the ssl cert from lets encrypt. Nginx gives the ssl cert so I was thinking this might be the problem?

Comment: the ssl cert (should) only effect the connection to your server ... not `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` or `ajax.googleapis.com` - since, I assume, neither of those belng to you

Comment: How does self signed certificates work then? Is this a known bug in chrome? But could chrome block it due to the certificate used?

Comment: what do self signed certificates have to do with any of this?

Comment: I was trying to pin point the issue by changing my ssl cert. Furthermore, without ssl the website loads all the external scripts.

Comment: and every other browser works just fine, except chrome - I think you've nailed the issue - *bug in chrome* - though, that's hardly news